# How to change this function from an automated one

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js

I have a function for a donut graph that does a cool transition every few seconds. I took some of it from a hw assignment and wanted to apply my idea to it as a function for myself. Pretty much I want it to be still and instead of shifting every few seconds I want it to shift when I press left or right keyboard button. Its written in javascript with d3. I still like the animation I just want to control with left and right instead of with time.

Function :

```
function transition(state) {
  var path = d3.selectAll(".arc > path")
      .data(state ? arcs(data0, data1) : arcs(data1, data0));

  // Wedges split into two rings.
  var t0 = path.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attrTween("d", tweenArc(function(d, i) {
        return {
          innerRadius: i & 1 ? innerRadius : (innerRadius + outerRadius) / 2,
          outerRadius: i & 1 ? (innerRadius + outerRadius) / 2 : outerRadius
        };
      }));

  // Wedges translate to be centered on their final position.
  var t1 = t0.transition()
      .attrTween("d", tweenArc(function(d, i) {
        var a0 = d.next.startAngle + d.next.endAngle,
            a1 = d.startAngle - d.endAngle;
        return {
          startAngle: (a0 + a1) / 2,
          endAngle: (a0 - a1) / 2
        };
      }));

  // Wedges then update their values, changing size.
  var t2 = t1.transition()
        .attrTween("d", tweenArc(function(d, i) {
          return {
            startAngle: d.next.startAngle,
            endAngle: d.next.endAngle
          };
        }));

  // Wedges reunite into a single ring.
  var t3 = t2.transition()
      .attrTween("d", tweenArc(function(d, i) {
        return {
          innerRadius: innerRadius,
          outerRadius: outerRadius
        };
      }));

  setTimeout(function() { transition(!state); }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add event listeners to respond to the key events in place of the `setTimeout` call.  [This chapter in Scott Murray's d3 text](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch10.html) should get you started.  In order to capture keyboard events, you'll need to make sure that your SVG can get the keyboard focus, which means giving it a [`tabindex` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets); you'll also need [code to figure out which key was pressed](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

Comment: Here's an example I put together for [an unrelated question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/51499/39778) that happens to use d3 and keyboard events: http://fiddle.jshell.net/jBk8h/2/